# decimalNumberByAdding doesn't seem to work for me?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, decimal

I have declared the below Variables:

```
NSDecimalNumber *gross_total = 0;
NSDecimalNumber *net_total = 0;
int *checks = 0;
NSString *current_check;
```

I have trying to Loop through each JSONElement to add all of the Values together to receive a Total which I have called 'gross_total'

```
for (int i = 0; i < TransactionArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = TransactionArray[i];


  NSDecimalNumber *gross = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:jsonElement[@"tran_value"]];

    gross_total = [gross_total decimalNumberByAdding:gross];


    // Accumulate if this is part of the previous check or a new one, add to INT Value for Check Count.

    if (jsonElement[@"tran_check"] == current_check){

    // DO NOTHING
    }
    else{
        //ADD TO THE CHECK COUNT
        checks++;

    }
    current_check = jsonElement[@"tran_check"];
}
```

Using the Breakpoints, I have discovered that the 'gross' gets a value from the 1st JSONElement of 3.4 which is great, however when it tried to use the decimalNumberByAdding function to accumulate 'gross_total' the value is NOT Passed to 'gross_total'.

I cant see what I am doing wrong, and would love some help ?

Comment: where did you declare those variables?

Comment: Just above the For Statement ...

Comment: Answer given by vadian should work. If it doesnt work, please update your question with what you tried!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber` is an object. You cannot declare it by simply assigning a literal scalar number.

A `NSDecimalNumber` with a value of zero can be declared

```
NSDecimalNumber *gross_total = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I am still getting my head round the Object/Variable thing. This worked Straight Away.

Comment: Out of Interest, do I have to use NSDecimalNumber to Store for example "2.35" or could I declare a float and parse the JSON String into that?

Comment: You can declare "2.35" as `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2.35"];`